# Solspace Calendar, ICS_Update & Google Calendars

Tags: solspace-calendar, google

I am having problems with Solspace Calendar 1.8.4 in EE 2.7.0 using the ICS Update function.

I've created a template with the following code:

```
{exp:calendar:ics_update calendar_id='179'}{/exp:calendar:ics_update}
```

I've verified that there is an entry with id 179 in the Calendar: Calendars channel that is 'open'. I've also confirmed that the following is in the "URL to iCalendar (.ics) file" field:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/canadian__en@holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics
```

When I browse to the template, I don't see any output at all (logged in as super admin). No items are imported into the calendar. The calendar was initially created without the ics URL filled in, but I have also tried creating a new calendar and adding the URL to the ics file at that time. Neither option has worked at this point, and I am attempting to get this done for my client this week.

Does anyone have experience with the ics_update that can point me in the right direction to get this fixed?

Comment: The latest version of Calendar is 1.8.5, which has EE 2.7 compatibility. Can you update Calendar and see if that helps? Also, having {exp:calendar:ics_update} alone on a template shouldn't have any output: everything should be happening in the background.

Comment: I managed to get the calendar to import events by making some changes in the code to patch a couple of bugs after Solspace support wasn't able to help after upgrades, patches applied, etc. I submitted he changes I made to them, so hopefully the next version will work for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the calendar to import events by making some changes in the code to patch a couple of bugs when Solspace support wasn't able to help after upgrades, patches applied, etc. I submitted the changes I made to Solspace.